# launching application after silent install

Tags: installshield

Installshield 2014 professional: Basic MSI (NOT setup.exe)

Using Project assistant, I set launch application checkbox (default `TRUE`) on `SetupCompleteSuccess` dialog.
Usually it works fine.
But on silent mode, it does not work.

How and When can I call `IS_LAUNCH_MY_PROGRAM_PLEASE` custom action or execute application on installed dirctory.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, my reaction to this is that you shouldn't do it. If you do, it should be conditional and require the person installing your software to include a property on the command line that requests the program launch.

That said, the problem is that the dialogs are not shown during a silent installation (Windows Installer skips the entire InstallUISequence), so the actions on them will never run. Instead you'd have to schedule a custom action in the InstallExecuteSequence, and use [UILevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372096.aspx) (and a custom property) to condition when this action runs.

Note that there's a strong likelihood that this will run your application in the wrong context, or even as the wrong user, as typically one has to pre-elevate in order for a silent installation to succeed. So again, keep the request to install an application and the request to run it separate. People using systems like SCCM will curse your installation otherwise.